# Why mysql order by alphanumeric not working

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-order-by

I am facing a problem with the MySQL query. The problem is
I have a table called 'members' and a column 'area'. In 'area' column there are alphanumeric values like

```
1
2
Street # 2
5
78
Street # 1A
Street # 1
Street # 1C
Street # 1B
3
```

Now What I want? I want to sort like this

```
1
2
3
5
78
Street # 1
Street # 1A
Street # 1B
Street # 1C
Street # 2
```

I tried almost every code but not fulfilling my requirements. Last code that is good but not as per my requirement. Currently, I have this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(area) FROM members ORDER BY LENGTH(area), area ASC
```

One thing that I want to clear that area filed has duplicate values in it.

I'll be thankful if someone helps me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the first part of the string and order it if it is a number:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (area regexp '^[0-9]') desc,        -- numbers first
         substring_index(area, ' ', 1) + 0,  -- by number
         area asc                            -- rest alphabetically
```

Note that this handles the awkward case where the initial number start with `0`.

And depending on how you want the strings ordered, you might still want to end with `len(area), area` as the last two `order by` keys.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a643bb4068ab81df214594002a39d8a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It is working on Db Fiddle website but not working on my system.

Comment: @MuhammadFaryad . . . How is it not working?  The db fiddle is there to show that the code works.

Comment: I said it the code is working on db fiddle but not working on my system. I am confused. I don't know why it is not working on my system. May be due to Mysql version

Comment: @MuhammadFaryad . . . This is pretty standard MySQL and has been supported pretty much forever.

Comment: I struggled for 6 to 8 hours and do everything I could but not getting my required results.

Comment: @MuhammadFaryad . . . Your comments are entirely unhelpful.  This answers your question.  It is demonstrated with the data you have specified, returning the results you have specified.  It runs in the database you have specified and in the oldest version on db<>fiddle , which dates back about 10 years.  This question is answered.  You may have further questions, which should be asked as a *new* question, with all the appropriate information.

Comment: You are right, the code you provided is working on db fiddble but why not on my server, this is the problem I am marking as answered but I am searching for help. However, thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your sample data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT area 
FROM members 
ORDER BY (area + 0 > 0 or area = '0') desc, area + 0, area
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=008067acd937ad7db271bfe361929bef)**:

```
| area        |
| :---------- |
| 1           |
| 2           |
| 3           |
| 5           |
| 78          |
| Street # 1  |
| Street # 1A |
| Street # 1B |
| Street # 1C |
| Street # 2  |
```

Comment: Of course it is working on DB Fiddle but not on my system.

Comment: @MuhammadFaryad: define *not working*. Are you getting an error? Wrong results (and if so, *what* is wrong with them)?

Comment: I am getting results, no error but not as expected. Street # 1
Street # 10
Street # 11
Street # 11A
Street # 11B

even there are 

Street # 1A
Street # 1B
Street # 1C

Answer (score 0):

One more query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(area)
FROM members 
ORDER BY 
    area+0=0 ASC, -- get numbers first
    area+0 ASC, -- order numbers
    area ASC; -- order strings
```

Live fiddle here [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=3cf85b353299a3b63112c1a61dde06c8&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)